# alertDialog set background size

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

There is a way to set the 'black' **background** size of the alertDialog?
I'm **not** meaning the **size of the alertDialog** but of his background that cover all the display.
I have an alert dialog that appears in a fragment where it has some tabs, the problem of the background of the alertdialog is that cover all the display, so i cannot tap on the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

[AlertDialog docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) and [AlertDialogBuilder docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) say that it is possible to change background - via AlertDialog(Context context, int theme) constructor for example, or providing Your own view for AlertDialogBuilder.

But I'm not sure if that's what You want - whole point of AlertDialog is to...be displayed for user to take action, so yes, it occludes Your fragments why wouldn't it? From Your post it looks like You are trying to move to other fragment while AlertDialog is displayed, if I understood correctly. But if just reading what's under - probably AlertDialogBuilder with custom view is way to go.